# How to cultivate sexual energy with Meditation?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation-effects, meditation, sexuality, energy

1. How a person can cultivate his own **sexual energy** to **creative one** with the help of Meditation?
2. can we handle Sexual energy when it arises with breathing technique or Meditation?

Comment: I would think that its important to define what is meant by the phrase 'sexual energy'. Is it sexual arousal, or the drive to go in search of sexual satisfaction?

Comment: @KaveengaWijayasekara yes it's asexual arousal, and not a drive to go in search for sexual satisfication..How to channelize this energy Upward??

Answer (score 5):

Mr/ Mrs Jyo Soudagar - Ajay should not cultivate it, if he/she meditates, but should abandon it, when ever such comes along. Listen to or read, Mr/Mrs Jyo Soudagar - Ajay, what was said in the [Bhikkhuni Sutta: The Nun](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.159.than_en.html), by Ven. Ananda.

Just considering the foulness of the body should help; or you may think on the drawbacks (disadvantages) of sensuality, to get disgusted.

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Answer (score 1):

I was taught a method by my Meditation Teacher for *transmuting* sexual energy, so that the energy could be turned to other uses. Seek a qualified Meditation Teacher who knows how to do this if you feel the need to know it.

This method and others like it may be used in everyday life to handle the arising of sexual (or other strong) feelings. There are lots of methods for managing your body, feelings, mind, etc, and even applying self-healing. Seek a qualified Meditation Teacher who knows these things, because even if you could learn it from a written source, what would you do when inevitably, you have questions about applying it?

Meditation is not just a technique, it is a full-round way of making the best of of everyday life.

Comment: Thank you@no comprende, but would you like to describe at list one method..

Comment: I am not a Meditation Teacher, I have not been given the blessing to teach it. I cannot pass on methods that I have only been taught to use myself. Additionally, some teachings are only given orally - at those times we were not even allowed to have notepads in the room while being taught. We were strongly warned that "helping" other people could do more harm than good. If you take your spiritual development seriously, you will search for a teacher. This is a life-long issue, not a stopgap.

Comment: OK.. thank you @no comprende... I will definetely find a teacher.. :)